# How can I find out which tab sound is coming from?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser-tabs

At times when I am using my web browser – normally Google Chrome – I hear sound playing and I am not sure where it's coming from.

I always do research our performing multiple tasks thus I have many tabs open. So I am wondering if there is a way of determining which tab has sound coming from instead of having to close/search all the tabs.

I'm currently using Windows 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an extension for Google Chrome that does this. It's called [**MuteTab**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mutetab/nmkbaaijgpppbokgnhhoakihofedkgcc).

> Helps narrow down which tab that sound is coming from, browser-wide granular mute controls, automatically mute background tabs

Comment: MuteTab is no longer available.

Comment: Found [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-playing-tab/hmbhamadknmmkapmhbldodoajkcggcml). Adds a buton with a list of tabs making sounds

Comment: [Go To Playing Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-playing-tab/hmbhamadknmmkapmhbldodoajkcggcml?hl=en-US). This is the way.

Answer (score 12):

I normally have numerous windows and tabs open and looking for a tab by the sound icon is a time consuming case of 'where is waldo'.

It's not a perfect solution but using the built in 'Task Manager' and sorting by 'Idle wakeups' column helps me find the culprit much quicker.

[image: locating tab playing music]

Comment: When the same answer addresses two different questions, there's a good chance the questions are duplicates.  Rather than post the same answer multiple times, it's better to flag one of the questions as a duplicate so they can be linked.  That makes it easier for readers to find the solutions that would otherwise be spread over several posts, and they might not be aware of the other post (and it helps avoid redundant information on the site).

Comment: What do you do once you find it? Kill it? Is there a way to bring it to front from the task manager?

Comment: @nycynik double click to activate and bring to front. It's not the Windows task manager, but the Chrome one. Shift-escape to activate.

Answer (score 3):

By the way, as of early 2014, Chrome has added a feature that shows which tabs are playing sound (a tiny speaker icon in the tab) -- other icons for tabs recording with your webcam, or chromecasting.

You'll see those now that you know to look for them, but just in case, here's the [Chrome blog post](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/01/everyone-can-now-track-down-noisy-tabs.html) describing the feature.